# Convert array values to longtoip

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm a novice php/js programmer and in the process of learning how to do things more efficiently with php and MySQL. I'm working on a personal project (a self learning exercise) by storing server ip's in a DB. A lot of pages on the web suggest the best method to store IPv4 addresses in MySQL is by using an integer field and converting the IPv4 address to store it. This is not a problem, it was pretty easy to do this.

However I am populating a data table and I pull the information back in the form of an array to populate each row. I have no idea how to convert these values back into a readable format using by longtoip when an array is involved. You will see in the output section below is where i'm running into issues most examples on the web don't deal with this sort of situation.

Please note I don't care about security in the rest of the code, I know it needs some work but i'll fix that up later (for those of you conscious of such things).

**Input:**

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$ipv4 = $_REQUEST['ipv4'];
$ipv6 = $_REQUEST['ipv6'];
$port = $_REQUEST['port'];
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password =$_REQUEST['password'];

$ipv4 = ip2long($ipv4);

require 'conn.php';

$sql = "insert into servers(name,ipv4,ipv6,port,username,password) values('$name','$ipv4','$ipv6','$port','$username',$password)";

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
//mysql_query($sql);
echo json_encode(array(
    'id' => mysql_insert_id(),
    'name' => $name,
    'ipv4' => $ipv4,
    'ipv6' => $ipv6,
    'port' => $port,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password
));
```

The result of inputting '192.168.1.1' into the ipv4 field produces the result '-1062731519' once written to MySQL.

**Output:**

```
<?php

require 'conn.php';

$rs = mysql_query('select * from servers');
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
    array_push($result, $row);
}

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Any simple methods on how to tackle this one is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this..

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
 $row->ipv4 = long2ip($row->ipv4);
 array_push($result, $row);
```

}

this usually update the $row object with new value.. try and let me know if this works

Comment: It did work, except I made a small mistake on the function syntax it's actually 'long2ip'. Thank you for this easily understandable response :)